# how to enable button conditionally in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ionic4

I am trying to enable button when distance is less than 1 KM . distance becomes less than 1 but button is not getting enables here is the code

```
  <ion-button @click="openWorkFinishModal" :disabled="this.disableStartWorkButton" color="danger"
          >Start Work</ion-button
        >
```

In js part

```
 data() {
    return {
      work_order: "",
      longitude: 0.0,
      latitude: 0.0,
      disableStartWorkButton: true,
    };
  },
  getLocation: function () {
      const geolocation = new GeolocationService.Geolocation();

      let watch = geolocation.watchPosition();
      watch.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("data",this.longitude,
            this.latitude);
        var distance =  this.checkDistance(
            data.coords.latitude,
            data.coords.longitude,
            this.latitude,
            this.longitude,
            
            "K"
          );
      
      
        if(distance < 1){
          this.disableStartWorkButton = false;
          console.log(this.disableStartWorkButton )

        }
     
      });
    },
```

You can see i am changing value of  `this.disableStartWorkButton`  to `false` when distance becomes less than 1 but it is not working

Comment: quick reaction: remove `this.` from your `:disable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `this.` should do the trick

```
:disabled="disableStartWorkButton"
```